# AngularJS- How to call controller's function on click of checkbox which is created in directive template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox, treeview

I am new to angularJS. I want to create checkboxes dynamically using templates in directives. I created controller and directives in separate files. I am creating checkbox in template in directive and want to invoke controller's function on ng-click of check box but I am unable to do so.
Here is my code sample.

```
Controller:
var app=angular.module('abc',[]);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.ctrlFn = function(test) {
         alert("hi "+test);
          console.log(test);
      }
});
```

I referred the https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview to create checkboxes tree view. I inlcuded all the css and js files in my sample. From the link I got the following js file which is creating the checkboxes in template in directive as shown below:

ivh-treeview.min.js:

```
angular.module("ivh.treeview",[]),
angular.module("ivh.treeview").directive("ivhTreeviewCheckbox",[function(){
    "use strict";
    return{restrict:"A",
        scope:{node:"=ivhTreeviewCheckbox"},
        require:"^ivhTreeview",
        link:function(a,b,c,d){
            var e=a.node,f=d.opts(),g=f.indeterminateAttribute,h=f.selectedAttribute;
            a.isSelected=e[h],
                a.ctrl=d,
                a.$watch(function(){return e[h]},function(b){a.isSelected=b}),
                a.$watch(function(){return e[g]},function(a){b.find("input").prop("indeterminate",a)})},
        template:['<input type="checkbox"','ng-model="isSelected"','ng-change="ctrl.select(node, isSelected)" />'].join("\n")}
}]);
```

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-8" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as demo">
                    <div ivh-treeview="demo.bag"
                         ivh-treeview-selected-attribute="'isSelected'"
                         ivh-treeview-id-attribute="'uuid'"
                         ivh-treeview-expand-to-depth="0">
                     </div>
</div>
```

I want to call ctrlFn() on click of checkbox created in directive template. Please suggest a way to do the same.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Would help to have a fiddle. You might also try with ng-controller in the inner div instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for a two-way binding between directive and parent $scope.

```
// parent controller scope
$scope.person = { name:'coldstar', class:'sexy beast' };

// directive declaration
<div a-person='person'></div>

// directive code
scope: {
    // the = sign is the key. could also be a function instead of object
    innerPerson: "=aPerson"
},
link: function (scope, elm, attr){
    // now this change will be reflect in the parent controller also
    scope.innerPerson.name = "not coldstar anymore";
}
```

Edit:

I also noticed "'isSelected'" which should be "isSelected" if isSelected is a $scope.* entity